# Send an IQueryable of arbitrary type to a general method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, iqueryable

The problem: I am trying to create a general method that will take in an `IQueryable` which can be many different types of data including custom. In this method I will be doing a sort depending on the type of `IQueryable` that is being passed in.

What I am doing is creating a custom class with the following:

```
public class sortObject
{
        public String OrderParam { get; set; }
        public int pageSize { get; set; }
        public int pageIndex { get; set; }//This is what page the user is on
        public IQueryable<dynamic> entity { get; set; }
}
```

I will pass in an IQueryable object to this object like so:

```
sortObject so = new sortObject();
so.entity = _context.userAcount.Select(x=>x);
...
```

The `so.entity` will be `IQueryable<dynamic>` but in the base section of the object (while in debugging) will be of type userAccount. I want the data in the base in order to run the search.

My issue is that I do not know what the `IQueryable` type is until run time since this is a general method. It can be of type user, or of type address etc, but the sorting will still work because I will pass in what I want to order this by in the sortObject.

How can I either get the base data or convert the `IQueryable` type at runtime?

I found that this works in the sort table method:

```
var entity = so.entity.AsQueryable().OrderBy("UserName");
var data = entity.Skip(so.pageSize*(so.pageIndex-1)).Take(so.pageSize);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is a solution involving generics - try

```
public class sortObject<T>
{
    public String OrderParam { get; set; }
    public int pageSize { get; set; }
    public int pageIndex { get; set; }//This is what page the user is on
    public IQueryable<T> entity { get; set; }
}
```

This will allow you to declare a `sortObject` with an `entity` of whatever type you want the `IQuerable` to contain.

You can make your method be something like

```
public void DoSomething<T>(sortObject<T> input)
{
    // input.entity is now of type T
}
```

and you can call

```
sortObject so = new sortObject<userAccount>();
so.entity = _context.userAcount.Select(x=>x);
DoSomething(so);
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, I also added something I came up.